# C: How to assign for loop characters = for loop values without printing(For equation purposes)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, variable-assignment, cs50

I'm new here, I wanted to know how I can make my automated(for loop) variables assign to my automated (for loop) values. In the example, I only printed it but, I want them to be used later on in a certain equation. I don't want to manually assign the values cause that's kinda copy pasting. This is a CS50 problem set, so I want it if you show the minimum amount of information for me to understand. See the Images for better understanding. Best Regards.

My Code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    long credit = get_long("What's your Credit Number?(No Hyphens) ");

        for (char letter= 'a'; credit != credit/10; letter++)
        {
        int take_credit = credit % 10;
        printf("%c = %i\n", letter, take_credit);//I WANT IT TO BE ASSIGNED SO I CAN SUM ALLTOGETHER
        credit= credit / 10;
        }
        printf("=a+b+c+d+e+f+g\n=4+1+2+0+0+4+1\n=12\n"); //THIS PART IS JUST FOR DEMONSTRATION
}
```

My Wanted Result:

```
What's your Credit Number?(No Hyphens) 1400214
a = 4
b = 1
c = 2
d = 0
e = 0
f = 4
g = 1
=a+b+c+d+e+f+g
=4+1+2+0+0+4+1
=12
```

Comment: Real CCNs (credit card numbers) have 13 or 16 digits, do they not?  How are you going to extend your code to handle both those possibilities?  Would you not be better off using an array?  You'll eventually need to understand the [Luhn Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Yes, This is just an example(I'm pseudo-coding). I've already understand Luhn Algorithm(as instructed by the course), for now, I want to simply assign each of the automated values with the automated variables. I'm still at lecture 1 but, if array is the only solution, I guess I would have learn it. Thanks for the suggestion.